# Why does my html below the content disappear when content is inserted?

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating a website for one of my modules, everytime I call information from the database to present onto the page all the html below this 'content div class' disappears, anyone know why??

Below is the php page for productions:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/productiontable.css">
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
require './db/connect.php';
include './includes/header.php'; 

?>
<h2>Productions</h2>

<div class="productiontable">
    <h3>What's on at this theatre</h3>
    <?php 
        if($result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Production")){
                        if($count = $result->num_rows){

                            while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    ?>
    <div class="centredinfo">
        <div class="coloumns">
            <div class="productionname">
                <?php echo $row->ProductionName; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="productiontype">
                <?php echo $row->ProductionType; ?>
            </div>
            <div class=""></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
     </div>            

    <?php           }
    $result->free();
            }
    } 
    echo $result; 
    mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>

    <p>please click on productions for more info</p>
</div>               

<?php include './includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

This is the maincss for the whole site:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?          family=Indie+Flower|Lobster|Pacifico|Dosis);

/*Reseting the design on the page*/
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}

/*Whole Page*/
body{
    font-family: 'Dosis';
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: bisque;
}

/*The box putting all information in middle*/
.container{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

/*Header*/
.header{
    width: 945px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px 1px 30px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -3px 1px 30px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    box-shadow: inset -3px 1px 30px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 82px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico';
}
.theatreleft, .theatreright{
    width: 80px; height: 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
}
.theatreleft{float: left;}
.theatreright{float: right;}

/*Navigation*/
.navigation{
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(top, grey 0%, black 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, grey 0%, black 100%); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, grey 0%, black 100%); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, grey 0%, black 100%); 
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: black 2px solid;
}
.navigation li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
.navigation li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center; 
}
.navigation li:first-child a{border-left: none;}
.navigation li:last-child a{border-left: none;}
.navigation li:hover > a{color: #00ccff;}
.navigation ul li a{
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
/*Sub Menu*/  
.navigation li ul{
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0;
     background: black;
     top: 40px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     -ms-border-radius: 5px;
}
.navigation ul li:hover > ul{
     opacity: 1;
}
.navigation ul li ul li{
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
.navigation ul li:hover > ul li{
     height: auto;
     overflow: visible;
}
.navigation ul li ul li a{
     width: 100px;
     margin-left: 22px;
     border: none;
     text-align: center;
}
.navigation ul li:first-child a{
     border: none; 
}

/*Content Below the navigation*/
.content{
    height: 500px;
    background-color: grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px 1px 30px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -3px 1px 30px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    box-shadow: inset -3px 1px 30px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    border: 2px black solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px; 
 }

 /*The paragraph element of the content box*/
 .content p{
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    width: 94%;
    margin: 10px;
 }

 /*Footer at the bottom*/
 .footer{
    background-color: grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px 1px 30px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -3px 1px 30px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    box-shadow: inset -3px 1px 30px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    border: 2px black solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

and the css for production table

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis);

h2{
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Dosis';
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
h3{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    margin: 20px;
}
.centredinfo{
    width: 900px;
}
.coloumns{
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.coloumns div{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

Anyone have an idea why??

Many Thanks

Comment: where is your call to the database? That is probably where the error is so we would need to see that

Comment: remove `error_reporting(0)`.. than see if you are getting any error or what...

Comment: Where do you use the `content div` in your html?

Comment: @nishantsolanki thank you so much was just the echo $result; causing it thank you for your help!!

Comment: If PHP just stops rendering partway through and leaves the rest of the page blank it means it's encountered an error. If you check the server's PHP log it will usually offer more detailed info about the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I removed error_reporting(0); to give me the error and showed that echo $result; was causing the problem, I have removed it and now it works perfectly. Many Thanks :)